# How can I send data between an activity and a non-activity class?

Tags: android, android-activity, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-alertdialog

I want to send data from a non-activity class to the MainActivity class and to show that data to the user using an AlertDialog. The data is a RemoteMessage from Firebase. I think I can use an interface but I tried some options and didn't work. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

**My non-activity class**

```
public class FcmMessageListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService  {
private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "CITYLINE_DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL";

public static final String MANDATOR_ID_KEY = "mandator_id";
public static final String MACHINE_SERIAL_NUMBER_KEY = "serial_number";
private iDialogNotificationInterface myInterface;
private  Map<String, String> data;

private Intent openAppIntent;
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    data = remoteMessage.getData();
    String mandatorId = data.get("mandatorID");
    String message = data.get("message");
    String serialNumber = data.get("pmID");
    if (message != null) {
        Log.i("OnMessageReceived: ", message);
        sendNotification(mandatorId, message, serialNumber);
        myInterface.sendDialogNotification(mandatorId, message, serialNumber);
    } else {
        Log.e("OnMessageReceived", "null error");
    }
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);

    SharedPrefsUtils.setBooleanValue(this, DEVICE_TOKEN_REFRESH_EVENT_KEY, true);
    SharedPrefsUtils.removeValueByKey(this, DEVICE_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_TOKEN_KEY);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceRegistrationService.class);
    startService(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String mandatorId, String message, String serialNumber){
    String notificationTitle = this.getString(R.string.app_name);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && notificationManager != null) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Default Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Status Change Notification");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }


    if (SharedPrefsUtils.getStringValue(this, SharedPrefsUtils.SESSION_COOKIE_DATA_KEY).equals("")) {
        openAppIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    } else {
        openAppIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    }
    openAppIntent.putExtra(MANDATOR_ID_KEY, mandatorId);
    openAppIntent.putExtra(MACHINE_SERIAL_NUMBER_KEY, serialNumber);
    TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(openAppIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_cityline)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_cityline))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    int notificationId = SharedPrefsUtils.getIntValue(this, SharedPrefsUtils.NOTIFICATION_UNIQUE_ID_KEY);

    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
        notificationId++;
        if (notificationId > 100000)
            notificationId = 0;
        SharedPrefsUtils.setIntValue(this, SharedPrefsUtils.NOTIFICATION_UNIQUE_ID_KEY, notificationId);
    }
}



 String id = mandatorId;
    String msg = message;
    String serial = serialNumber;

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("ID", id);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("MSG", msg);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("SERIAL", serial);
```

}

**MainActivity**

```
private void openNotificationDialog( String mandatorId, String message, String serialNumber){

    Log.i("RAZZ", getApplicationContext().toString());
    String notificationTitle = this.getString(R.string.app_name);
    infoDialog = mBuilder.create();
    mBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    infoDialog.setTitle(notificationTitle);
    infoDialog.setMessage(message);
    infoDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            infoDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    infoDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    infoDialog.show();
}


@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

    }

@Override
public void sendDialogNotification(String id, String message, String serialNmb) {
    openNotificationDialog(id, message, serialNmb);
}
```

**The interface**

```
public interface iDialogNotificationInterface {
 void sendDialogNotification(String id, String message, String serialNmb);
```

}

Comment: Where are you giving any value to "myInterface" ? How can you call         myInterface.sendDialogNotification(mandatorId, message, serialNumber);
 if myInterface is null?

Comment: That's what I tried in the code posted here but I get the null object reference exeption.. In the FcmMessageListener class I created a data member of type iDialogNotificationInterface and called the specific method with the right params. And inside my MainActivity I implemented that interface and created the implementation of the method (calling the method which shows the alertDialog). But it's not working..

Comment: @DanBaruch but what value should I give to myInterface?... I dont know exactly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of interface should go as follows:

```
public class A implements interfaceA{
private interfaceA dataMember;
public void setMember(interfaceA member)
{
dataMember = member;
}
// rest of class code
// when needed to notify interfacemember, you call dataMember.function()
}
```

in your MainActivity you should do something like

```
FcmMessageListenerService obj.setMember(MainActivity.this)
```

From you code it seems you are using a service and not a class. As it's a service I'd send the data to MainActivity via intent rather than interface.

Comment: I need to take the message from a notification and everytime the user receive a notification I need to show an alertDialog with the notification's message.

Comment: So your recommendation for me is to use an intent to send the data to the MainActivity?

Comment: change your private void sendNotification(String mandatorId, String message, String serialNumber) to follow: String vala = mandatorid;
                String path = message;
String serNum = serialNumber;
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                serviceIntent.putExtra("VAL1", vala);// same for other values
                serviceIntent.setPackage(context.getPackageName());
                context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(serviceIntent);

Comment: Meh, the comment gives too little space to write... I meant, keep the code of your current function, after you have finished all the things you need with the data and you wish to update the ActivityClass, you use an intent, with the example I gave you in the previous comment to pass values through the intent. In your mainActivity you then override onNewIntent and parse the intent there to make sure you got the intent you needed with the right information and from there you can call any function you need.

Comment: I updated the question with the code you suggested added. Can you check please? Thanks

Comment: But what code should I write inside the onNewIntent in the MainActivity? Thanks

Comment: if (intent.hasExtra("your_value")) {
            string strA = intent.getStringExtra("your_value", ""); // same for all other strings and then call openNotificationDialog(strA, strB, strC)
            }
        }

Comment: And this code will work for every notification I receive?

Comment: It should, as when ever you receive a notification you are sending an intent to your mainActivity, it should capture everything.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying now this option and right after that I'll notice you here if it works.

Comment: can you help me with a simillar issue? I need to check if an activity is opened or not from that Service class which is a non-activity class. Is that possible?

Comment: @RazvanAndrei what do you mean by "open"? If it's running? even if it's in the background?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sharepreference to store data in the Non-Activity class and then fetch the data into your Activity class and vice versa.

In Non-Activity class

**Initialization**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

**Storing Data**

```
editor.putBoolean("IsNotificationReceived", true); // Storing boolean as true when you receive the notifiaction also store the body or message into this sharedpref form the notification 
editor.commit(); // commit changes !Important line to save data into the sharedpreference
```

In Activity class

**Retrieving Data**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
boolean isNotificationReceived = pref.getBoolean(IsNotificationReceived, false);
```

check for isNotificationReceived on onResume or when you init the class if the value is true then call for dialog and show the appropriate message

Make sure to edit sharedpref isNotificationReceived to false when you open the dialog otherwise the dialog will open whenever you init the class wheather you received the notification or not